Как связать админку и доступ к странице django
Пишу сайт на django, и столкнулся с проблемой: нужно чтобы человек, который в админке находится в группе earlyAccess имел доступ к странице, которая находится в разработке, а при этом другим высвечивалась страница - заглушка.

Вы можете сделать это по меньшей мере двумя способами.
Первый способ (правильный) - в views.py генерировать view в зависимости от прав пользователя:
def show_page(request): 
    if request.user.has_perm('app_name.permission_name'):
        #render page
    esle:
        #render placeholder

Второй - прописать условия отображения в template в формате
{% if perms.appn_ame.permision_name %}

